# How do I add a $comment to a distinct or aggregate call using the Java driver for mongodb?

Tags: java, mongodb, driver

I'm using mongodb with the Java driver. I want to add a $comment to every call I make to the database.

For find I use the addSpecial method on DBCursor with a $comment key.

How would I add a similar $comment to aggregate and distinct calls made on DBCollection?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At present neither of these commands return a cursor.

The [distinct](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/distinct/) command is an old interface and you should avoid using it in your code in favour of using aggregate instead.

The [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/command/aggregate/) command will support a cursor from the 2.6.x production release and upwards. In the future you will be able to do the same thing by passing in arguments to the creation of the cursor, but for now you cannot.